# Copy value from row 2 of df column to row 1 (with datetime index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
# create an array of 5 dates starting at '2015-02-24', one per minute
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'Oth' : np.random.randn(len(rng)) }) 
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
```

Where the value on row 1 for one variable (e.g. 'Val') is NA

```
df.iloc[0,1] = 'NA'
```

I want to copy the value from row 2 of the `Val` column to row 1, and I can do so using:

```
df['Val'].iloc[0] = df['Val'].iloc[1]
```

However this gives the error:

```
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:671: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

I will be performing this assignment on lots of dataframes, so want to make sure I'm avoiding any issues, and this warning seems like it might cause problems. I can't figure out how to avoid it in this case, I have tried:

```
df.iat[0, 1] = df.iat[1, 1]
```

And this works, however I would like to specify the column name, and not use `iat` and the integer numbers, and when I try this:

```
df.at[0,'Val'] = df.at[1, 'Val']
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers
```

So this works if I don't have a datetime Index, but I want to keep my datetime index!
I would appreciate any help/advice.
Thank you.

Comment: you really should be using `loc`. `df.loc[0,"Val"] = df.loc[1,"Val"]`

Comment: @rob This gives the error `TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>`